# How can i check the duration of connection in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I believe `Max_used_connections` is the number of mysql connections are still open and are not closed yet.

```
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max | 0     |
| Max_used_connections     | 22    |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used    | 0     |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Here i want to see the list of connections with the duration how long this connection is being used. And when this connection is going to be killed. (wait_timeout variable)

```
| Variable_name            | Value | Start Time | Aprox End Time | Hours (Use)
+--------------------------+-------+
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max | 0     |
| Max_used_connections     | 22    |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used    | 0     |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

I set `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` to 2 and still 22 connections are open. I waited for 30 minuets, i see there is no change in the Max_used_connections variable.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your server to see a change of that variable, because, as the manual says, it holds *The maximum number of connections that have been in use simultaneously since the server started.*